# Bridged wireless with parprouted: Is there a way to do the same with IPv6?

Tags: ipv6, bridge

[Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/197156/set-tap0-using-virt-manager-for-bridged-wireless) is an example of how to bridge a wireless device with parprouted:

On the host:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
sudo tunctl -t tap0
sudo ip link set tap0 up
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.25/24 dev tap0
sudo route add -host 192.168.1.30 dev tap0
sudo parprouted wlan0 tap0
```

On the guest:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.30
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.1.0
  broadcast 192.168.1.255
  gateway 192.168.1.25
```

But parprouted only supports IPv4.

In the Wikipedia article about [Neighbor Discovery Protocol (NDP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_Discovery_Protocol) there is the following citation:

*"Neighbor Discovery Proxy (ND Proxy) (RFC 4389) provides a service similar to IPv4 Proxy ARP and allows bridging multiple network segments within a single subnet prefix when bridging cannot be done at the link layer."*

I have a wireless card with this configuration (my MAC address is random):

```
$ ip address show dev enp3s0
2: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_pie state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3a:25:eb:5b:a9:dc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 88:d7:f6:41:c3:e5
    inet 192.168.1.4/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft 5245sec preferred_lft 5245sec
    inet6 xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:bfa8:8e6c:4f5c:4e9a/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 602848sec preferred_lft 83933sec
    inet6 xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:ce14:2ded:2fd3:4bde/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 2591856sec preferred_lft 604656sec
    inet6 fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I want to "bridge" the wireless card (wlan0) to a TAP virtual interface and set in the guest the address of the TAP as the default gateway, just like the example above. And of course, assigning a new IPv6 to the TAP interface.

How can I bridge the wireless device (which cannot be bridged directly with **brctl** tool) to a TAP virtual interface and enable IPv6 communication between bridge/tap and the wifi interface?

Remembering, my IPv6 addresses are configured using SLAAC in the router.

Comment: Nearest tool would be `ndppd`. But you shouldn't write "bridge" since neither tools are bridging.

Comment: I didn't know this ndppd, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Please describe these networks, what you would like to happen, and what you have attempted.

Comment: @JohnMahowald I added more info.